# Page refresh 404 error in Next.js 13.4 version after deploy on AWS and Where is the actual build folder for deployemnt

Tags: amazon-web-services, build, http-status-code-404, next.js13

I need some help as I am using nextjs 13.4 version for app building and deploying it on AWS but after deploying on every page refresh I got a 404 error message, and also need to know where the main index.html file in .next build folder located, Thanks

I tried to deploy my nextjs 13.4 app on aws but after deploying it on every page refresh a got 404 error.